# Axis web service response name spaces issue?

Tags: web-services, jaxb, apache-axis

I'm writing a web-service with Axis and getting request as below.

```
<NS13:PrefixCd xmlns:NS13="http://abc/def/common/name">MR</NS13:PrefixCd>
<NS14:FirstNm xmlns:NS14="http://abc/def/common/name">ARTURO</NS14:FirstNm>
<NS15:LastNm xmlns:NS15="http://abc/def/common/name">DOPAZO</NS15:LastNm>
```

In the request every element have namespace and in my response all the namespaces are in root element.
It is possible to put the namespaces in element level in the response.
I have used jaxb to create my skeleton. Please give some advice to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

JAXB - to the best of my knowledge - does not support this kind of customization. You could use XSLT to customize your response...